# Printing a string of a object in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have this code and I want to print the 'Make Breakfast' not the id of the object, I've tried a lot of things but every time is printing the ID not the string which is what I want.

```
require_relative 'Task'
class List
  attr_reader :all_tasks
  def initialize
    @all_tasks = []
  end
  def add(task)
    all_tasks << task
  end
  def show
    all_tasks
  end
end
if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  my_list = List.new
  puts 'You have created a new list'
  my_list.add(Tasks.new('Make Breakfast'))
  puts "You've added a item to the item list"
  puts my_list.show
end
```

Comment: But `my_list` is essentially an array of Tasks. What if you had two tasks? What would you print?

Comment: I have seen several question like this. A new course assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are having a `name` attribute in your `Task` class.

```
class Task
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

Now we have a `List` class that will have many tasks. I make a small change. What I do is to add a `#to_s` method. This method will take all of your tasks and extract their `name` attribute. The `#to_s` is what used in string "#{my_list}" interpolation and in places like `puts`.

```
class List
  attr_reader :all_tasks

  def initialize
    @all_tasks = []
  end

  def add(task)
    all_tasks << task
  end

  def show
    all_tasks
  end

  def to_s
    # here i am using 'name' attribute on my assumption.
    # map will make an array of names
    # the join will join the array of names with ', '
    all_tasks.map(&:name).join(', ')
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  my_list = List.new
  puts 'You have created a new list'
  my_list.add(Task.new('Make Breakfast'))
  puts "You've added a item to the item list"
  puts my_list  # Note that i removed the all_tasks and using #to_s
end
```

Comment: Thanks man, resolved my problem. Now I can keep building my project. Cheers

Comment: Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `to_s` method in every object to change how they are printed, in your case, you want Task#to_s to show the text inside the task and List#to_s to display every task in the list, probably joining them together:

```
# Inside Task
def to_s
  all_tasks.map(&:to_s).join("\n")
end
```

`map(&:to_s`) will return an array with the result of calling `to_s` on each task, and join will put a new line between them.

Comment: I added this code but still printing the ID of the object

Comment: Did you change how Tasks are shown into a string (changed Tasks#to_s)? What does `puts Task.new('foo')` gives you?

Comment: I think you meant `# Inside List` for the example code provided.